# App crashes when adding names to UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

When I click a button, a UIAlertView prompts the user to type a name.  This name is then created as a new 'Customer' object and inserted into a mutable array.

There is a separate mutable array called 'CustListByName', which stores a list of all names.

The problem im having is that when adding a second or third name, the app crashes.  Sometimes it happens on the second try, other times on the third try.  There is no information given in the debugger except for (lldb).  The program reports EXC_BAD_ACCESS and then it dumps me to a screen with a bunch of assembly code.

The crash is happening in these lines of code:

Essentially, it clears the array of names and then repopulates it based upon the object array.  I've studied in step by step with a breakpoint but everything seems correct up until the point of crash.  It is also confusing why this happens on the second or third try, never the first.

```
[custListByName removeAllObjects];
    for (Customer *object in custListByObject) {
        [custListByName addObject:object->name];
    }
```

Here is the code where a customer is created and inserted everytime the new customer button is clicked:

```
   Customer *tempCust = [[Customer alloc] init];
    tempCust->name =[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
    [custListByObject addObject:tempCust];
    [tempCust release];
```

I would really appreciate help with this, thanks!

Comment: Can I assume that the NSMutableArray you are manipulating is the same array that is being used as the data source for the UIPicker?

Comment: instead of making tempCust-> a public variable, create a proprerty of type copy.

Comment: @darkfoxmrd - Yes, custListbyName is the data source for the UIPicker.

Comment: @Justin do you mean change the declaration to property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* name;"

Comment: @johnhannigan @property(nonatomic, copy)NSString* name; in the header then code becomes tempCust.name =

Comment: try calling the 'reloadAllComponents' method on the picker view right after removeAllObjects on the array, and before you repopulate the array in your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

What I suspect is happening is that the UIPickerView is attempting to load a row using information from your customer array after you have already cleared it, and before you repopulate it.  This would cause a bad access error.

What you may consider doing instead, is keeping two arrays, an NSMutableArray for loading the customers, and an NSArray as the actual data source for the UIPickerView.  Then right before you reload the UIPickerView, you say:

```
dataSourceArray = [loadingArray copy];
[pickView reloadAllComponents];
```

Hopefully this helps.

Edit:

Here's what your updated code would look like if your loading array was called loadingCustListByName:

```
[loadingCustListByName removeAllObjects];
    for (Customer *object in custListByObject) {
        [loadingCustListByName addObject:object->name];
    }
custListByName = [loadingCustListByName copy];
[pickView reloadAllComponents];
```

Doing this will ensure that the UIPickerView's datasource array always matches up with the number of rows it thinks it has.